# Sprite Bouncing when It Shouldnt

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I am making a 2D game where a character is standing on top of a platform. The character is affected by gravity but the platform is not. Restitution on both objects is set to 0. Once I utilize this code to make the platform slowly drop, the character goes down with it since it is standing on top of the platform. However, the character is bouncing up and down slightly as the platform is dropping. How can I prevent that? The faster the platform drops, the faster and more obvious the bounce is.

```
[SKAction moveTo:(CGPointMake(xCoord,yCoord) duration:(10)];
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I believe it has to do with the fact that even though restitution is set to 0, the sprite is still slightly bouncing off walls and other objects.

Comment: you should set the character.physicsBody.mass or the character.physicsBody.density to 10 more.

Comment: No matter how high I set the mass/density/friction to, it still seems to bounce. The faster the platform drops, the more obvious the bounce is.